# How do I detect Ctrl+Key in Python without having to download other modules?

Tags: python

I am writing a command-line notepad program and I want to detect keyboard press combinations, for example, Ctrl+S and Ctrl+D.
I have found many codes which work, but they all require me to download a module, like the keyboard module.
However, my parents have set restrictions such that I am not able to download any modules.
Could someone give me an alternative to the following code:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("ctrl+s"):
        print("Ctrl+s is pressed!")
```

**without** having to download external modules?

Comment: Which platform and python version are you using?

Comment: @CONvid19 Windows 10 and Python 3.8.2, I'm writing my code in pycharm.

Comment: @fez-tival  I added a small delay on the loop cycles to avoid high cpu load.

Comment: @CONvid19 thankuuu! :) it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on windows, you can use the built-in [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) module, i.e.:

```
import msvcrt
from time import sleep

while 1:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        # print(key) # uncomment to see which keys are being pressed.
        if key == b"\x13":
            print("CTRL+S")

    sleep(0.05) # Added to reduce cpu load, 5% before, 0.01% after
```

---

Notes:

Run it on a console, not inside the IDE.

- `python3 myscript.py`

Comment: What about readers who are on MacOS?